# Output string to csv file line space problems

Tags: php, csv, str-replace, put

I am using the following to save the stripped out contents of a page to a csv file on my server.

```
$strippedpage = str_replace('<br>',' ', $semistrippedpage);
    file_put_contents('yourpage.csv', $strippedpage);
```

before this in the code I basically just use str_replace to remove all the html and format it like a csv file.

```
    1-Do you like Science?,
    5,2
    1,6
    3,7
    6,8
    7,9
    85,Love
    6,Ok
    15,Strongly Dislike
    2- Do you enjoy science lessons at school?,
    1,3
    1,4
    5,7
    4,8
    2,9
    78,Love
    21,Ok
    16,Strongly Dislike
    3-How often do you use ICT in Science Lessons? (E.g. microscopes digital cameras easi-speak mics.),
    29,2
    8,3
    11,4
    20,6
    4,7
    27,In Some Lessons
    29,Not At All
```

The only html remaining in the string is BR tags to separate the lines.

If I copy and paste the output above from the browser to a notepad doc and save it as a csv it opens fine and displays each line as a separate line.

The problem I am having is if I open the generated 'yourpage.csv' file on the server I get the following :

```
1-Do you like Science?, 5,2 1,6 3,7 6,8 7,9 85,Love 6,Ok 15,Strongly Dislike 2- Do you enjoy science lessons at school?, 1,3 1,4 5,7 4,8 2,9 78,Love 21,Ok 16,Strongly Dislike 3-How often do you use ICT in Science Lessons? (E.g. microscopes  digital cameras  easi-speak mics.), 29,2 8,3 11,4 20,6 4,7 27,In Some Lessons 29,Not At All 4-How often do you get to do practical Science in lessons?, 1,No Answer 17,2 8,3 14,4 4,6 8,7 5,8 1,9 11,In Every Lesson 56,In Some Lessons 3,
```

For some reason it just bungs it all on one line, im not sure how you add the csv equivalent of a line break into the code so that each result is on a separate line like the example I posted above.

Comment: The end-of-line is not the same on Windows and unix systems : http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html. Notepad wants Windows line-endings, while other editors (notepad++,ultraedit,...) are able to "understand" Unix line-endings. I would suggest using one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$strippedpage = str_replace('<br>',"\n", $semistrippedpage); //for new line
file_put_contents('yourpage.csv', $strippedpage);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of stripping away br's, you might want to replace them with new line tags

I.E> `$nl = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $html);`

might get you heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the newline character is usually `\n`, whereas `\r\n` is used in most Windows programs (such as Notepad).

Because of that, Windows Notepad doesn't identifies the line breaks.

Try opening your CSV file with another editor ([Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.3.html) for instance) and see if you get the same result.

Also, I would advise you to use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to generate your CSV file instead of a simple `str_replace`, as it is much safer (for example, it can handle special characters).